# Get result from downstream function in generator

Tags: python, callback, generator, return-value

I'm struggling to figure out how to achieve an implementation like the following in python:

```
def a_generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
        # if [downstream function returns false]:
        #     break
    cleanup()


def cleanup():
    # Do some cleanup task
    pass


def handle_each_value(i):
    if i > 10:
        return False
    return True


for value in a_generator():
    continue_processing = handle_each_value()
    # Cause the generator to run `cleanup()` if `continue_processing == False`
```

Is there a way to do this, whether with callbacks or as a generator?

Comment: Can you explain why do you not want to cleanup from the outer loop? It seems to make more sense - even using a for-else construct.

Comment: The generator belongs to a library - I'd rather not have to rewrite it differently myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`generator.close`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.close) feature:

```
def a_generator():
    i = 0
    try:
        while True:
            print('yield', i)
            yield i
            i += 1
    finally:
        cleanup()


def cleanup():
    # Do some cleanup task
    print('cleaned up')
    pass


def handle_each_value(i):
    if i > 10:
        return False
    return True

gen = a_generator()
for value in gen:
    continue_processing = handle_each_value(value)
    if not continue_processing:
        gen.close()
```

Sample output:

```
yield 0
yield 1
yield 2
yield 3
yield 4
yield 5
yield 6
yield 7
yield 8
yield 9
yield 10
yield 11
cleaned up
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a version: you can use `cont = yield i` inside the generator in order to get a value from outside it (which is sent by `gen.send(value)`):

```
def a_generator():
    i = -1
    while True:
        cont = yield i
        if cont == False:
            break
        i += 1
    cleanup()

def cleanup():
    print("cleanup")

def handle_each_value(i):
    if i > 10:
        return False
    return True

gen = a_generator()
next(gen)  # need to prime the generator in order to call .send()
continue_processing = True
try:
    while True:
        value = gen.send(continue_processing)
        continue_processing = handle_each_value(value)
        print(value)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```